# Access Ajax request data

Tags: ajax, octobercms, october-partial

can you help me please?

-- I've making ajax call to partial and sending the data ( productId )

$.request('onProductLoad', {
data: {'productId': 22},
update: { 'Product/card': `#result`}
})

how i can access this data in function onProductLoad() in the php code tab  on a page that partial is placed in.

Thank you!

Comment: you can access it inside `onProductLoad` in post data `$data = post();`

Answer (score 0):

Add a function called `onProductLoad` to the page and you can access the posted data as you would normally do in a component.

```
title = "My Page"
url = "/"
layout = "default"
==
<?
function onProductLoad()
{
    $productId = post('productId');
}
?>
==
```